# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException with UCanAccess

Tags: java, mysql, ms-access, java-8, ucanaccess

I am trying to connect to an Access database with Java 8 like in this answer :

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc)

I am unfamiliar with the creation/design of the DB.

The connection seems to work because I get a few error messages like this :

> WARNING:Error in the metadata of the table MB02: table's row count in
>   the metadata is 556 but 557 records have been found and loaded by
>   UCanAccess. All will work fine, but it's better to repair your
>   database.

And I have this method trying to pull something out of the DB with an SQL SELECT Statement :

```
public void searchDatabase()
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

    Connection con = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess:///C:/Users/Blabla.mdb");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM MB01";

    ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while(resultSet.next()){
        System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
    }

}
```

I keep getting this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
>   Dangling meta character '?' near index 19 MB  01  BEZAHLT  ???
>                      ^  at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)   at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.SQLConverter.replaceWhiteSpacedTableNames0(SQLConverter.java:547)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.SQLConverter.replaceWhiteSpacedTables(SQLConverter.java:526)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.SQLConverter.convertSQL(SQLConverter.java:372)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.SQLConverter.convertSQL(SQLConverter.java:472)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.convertSQL(UcanaccessStatement.java:57)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:206)
>     at DBCrawler.searchDatabase(DBCrawler.java:27)

Line 27 is where the error is thrown is :

```
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

The thing is I can leave the query String empty or put any nonsense values in it and I still get the error.

Where do I start searching for the problem or how can I fix this?

Comment: Problem seem to come from the database itself. Check if there is a character that could be mistaken for a wildcard somehow.

Comment: Are you using the same ucanaccess version of the console? Pay attention...

Comment: Also the ucanaccess version you're using seems to be very old...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an Access database with a table named `19 MB 01 BEZAHLT ???` and was able to reproduce your issue with UCanAccess 3.0.5. The problem <strike>will be</strike> was fixed in <strike>a future release of</strike> UCanAccess 3.0.6.